# Eclipse cannot resolve package name

Tags: java, eclipse

I have started to learn Java along with Eclipse and the book "*Thinking in Java*" by Bruce Eckel. I tried to add his `util` package (from `net.mindview.util`) to a project but Eclipse complains the name cannot be resolved.

I added an external folder `net`. It contains other folders `atunit`, `simple` and `util` which containts uncompiled `*.java` files. In Java Build Path -> Libraries, I have pointed at the external class folder:

[image]

but Eclipse still cannot resolve the package name:

[image]

For me, everything seems OK and the package structure is correctly organised in folders:

[image]

Just in case, I also checked whether files correctly specify package name:

[image]

I run out of options. The [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-properties-build-path.htm) just shows how to add external folders and does not say what to do if there are problems.

Hopefully someone can help with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got one directory too far when adding the library to the build path. The library should be showing up as `TIJ4Code`, in the `Java` directory. (Or in other words, when you choose "Add class folder" you should be choosing `TIJ4Code`, not `net`.)

That way `net` becomes the first part of the package name - whereas Eclipse is currently treating `net` as the "root" directory of the library, so it thinks that `Print` "should" be in a package of `mindview.util` for example.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the folder and Eclipse seems to be resolving the package name if I type `import net.mindview.util.*;` with star but it still doesn't recognize classes inside `util`! E.g. if I want to use `Print.print()`, Eclipse doesn't see this method is defined. It does not see the class Print.

Comment: @Celdor: Have you actually *compiled* the code? It's meant to be a *class* folder - if you've only got the source code, that's probably what's wrong. At that point it may be simpler to add the code as a new project with the relevant source location, then add that project to your build path. (Or you could just add the folder as an extra source location to your main project, of course.)

Comment: I've done both options: adding external source and creating a new project which I added to existing project. Both methods worked :) Thanks for help.

Comment: It took me some time to work out everything but I guess it is the part of learning curve! Meantime I tried to test simple classes in different packages and with different access modifiers. Eclipse was complaining all the time. What I eventually realised was that I forgot to make either constructors or classes public -.-